# Visual Studio 2017 Global Declaration

Tags: variables, global-variables

Here I want to generate a number (n) of  random number into a listbox and then using another listbox to show the generated random number in accending order.

Since it is separated into two private class, i tried to use public shared for my array mark() but it doesn't seems to work.

This is my complete code. 
I have no issue generating the random number into my array mark() as i declared it in the private sub.

But when I do the sorting using another button, it shows error that I did not declare my array. If I re-declare my array, the number that i stored in it will be gone and the sorting turns into all 0.

Any idea how?

```
Public Class Form1

Dim n As Integer
Public Shared mark() As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim temp As Integer

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim i As Integer

    n = Val(TextBox2.Text)
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    i = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim mark(n - 1) As Integer

    For i = 0 To n - 1

        mark(i) = Format("#", Rnd() * 100)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(mark(i))
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    ListBox2.Items.Clear()

    For i = 0 To n - 1
        For j = 0 To n - 2
            If mark(j) > mark(j + 1) Then
                temp = mark(j)
                mark(j) = mark(j + 1)
                mark(j + 1) = temp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For k = 0 To n - 1
        ListBox2.Items.Add(mark(k))
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You has to be more specific. What doen't work sorting  or thr variable is not accesible or ..... Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the Visual Studio IDE. Please tag correctly and read [ask].

Comment: @tambre , this has to do with visual studio because my friend who is using Visual Basic has no problem declaring a Global array.

Comment: @Szekuns In that case it has to do with whatever interpreter/compiler you're executing it with. Visual Studio is simply an IDE - it displays code, highlights it and allows you to easily invoke the actual runtime/interpreter/compiler.